# Using react-table <VariableSizeList> with react-window could not achieve both at same time 1.Virtulization 2.Sticky columns on scroll

Tags: reactjs, virtualization, sticky, react-window

```
I am using  for achieving virtualization. But not able to apply the property of sticky to the same.

     handleScroll(e, TableRef)}
        className="variable-size"
    >
    {RenderRowVirtualized}
```

So by using above and overriding the CSS of overflow => auto to unset I am able to achieve sticky column but the virtualization is removed

[want to make the Row Index sticky and have virtualization at same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErW7D.png)

[want to make the Row Index sticky and have virtualization at same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzYPu.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please refer the following question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77149701/use-virtualization-and-sticky-property-with-variablesizelist-instead-of-variable