# Use virtualization and sticky property with VariableSizeList instead of VariableSizeGrid

Tags: reactjs, virtualization, sticky, react-window

I am using VariableSizeGrid with which I am able to achieve virtualization and sticky properties .
The code example is in below link.

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-window-sticky-grid-forked-x3rx2j)

I need to achieve the same with VariableSizeList. Can you suggest on this?
Thanks!!